# Jquery multple post request in sequence

Tags: jquery, post, get

I need to send three get/post requests. From the response of the first one, I populate an array of objects like this.

```
mylist=[];
$.post(url,{param1:p1},function(data){
    for (i=1; i<=data.length; i++){
        mylist.push({
            v1:val1, 
            v2:val2
        });
    }
});
```

Now, I need to send another request and from its response, I need to update a member of the array of objects.

So, I update the code as

```
mylist = [];
$.post(url, {
    param1: p1
}, function(data) {
    for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
        mylist.push({
            v1: data[i].val1,
            v2: data[i].val2
        });
        // next request
        $.get(url, {
            param1: p2
        }, function(data2) {
            for (i = 1; i <= data2.length; i++) { //compare and replace
                new_attr = data2[i].newval1;
                for (j = 1; j <= mylist.length; j++) {
                    if (mylist[j].v1 == new_attr) { //error line
                        mylist[j].val2 = data2[i].newval2;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        displayData(myList);
    }
});
```

But when I do so, I get this error on the line indicated by the error line comment in the code.

> Unable to get property 'v1' of undefined or null reference.

What am I doing wrong? I also tried to use $.when() before the get/post and calling the display function in .done() but still the same error.

Comment: your data json hasn't got a value val1

Comment: Sorry, my bad, have edited the question, the error is on v1

Comment: The main problem is that AJAX calls are asynchronous.

Comment: The error which you are getting is because first loop `mylist[j].v1` will be `mylist[1].v1`, since `mylist[1]` is not defined, it will throw error.

Comment: Could you suggest me a solution to do this synchronously? I am unable to understand the comment. If I check mylist.length before the next request, I have 10 entries in the list.